# Problems in VB6 with DOMDocument60 (xml) in Windows 8.1

Tags: xml, vb6, windows-8.1, domdocument

I'm trying to create a xml document and I'm getting a problem.
I can use DOMDocument with OS win 7 and Lower, and all works fine. 
But with OS win 8.1 i have reference problems and i cant use DOMDocument, so I have to use DOMDocument60

CODE:

```
Private Sub AddNodeEncoding(xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)
Dim varAux As Variant
    Set varAux = xDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""")
    xDoc.appendChild varAux    
End Sub

Private Sub AddNodeRoot(xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)
Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, xAttr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim strNS As String    
    Set xNode = xDoc.createElement(lcStrRootNamespace) 
    Set xAttr = xNode
    strNS = GMEDIAAD_XMLNS
    If strNS = "" Then strNS = GetXMLSchemaPath(False)
    xAttr.setAttribute "xmlns", strNS
    xAttr.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xAttr.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xDoc.appendChild xNode
End Sub
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><OrdensElectronicas xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="..."/>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OrdensElectronicas xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="..."/>
```

I need a break line before `<OrdensElectronicas...` and I dont know how to do it.
We also have a formating function, but doesn't work for the root element.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try [this snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note the preserveWhiteSpace property.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant. TThanks for your answer. Yes, I see your point here. With the preserveWhiteSpace turned off it works. I wil do a couple more tests and see if it fits. Thank you!